# Laravel - Dynamic select menu

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

I'm trying to dynamically set options in a select menu by first selecting an option in the first select menu.

Example: The user selects a company in one select menu. In the second select menu the locations that belong to the selected company are set.

Here is my view

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control admin-select" name="admin-select">
                    <option>- Select -</option>
                    <option value="1">Company 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Company 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Company 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select id="location" class="form-control" name="location">
                    <option>- Select -</option>
                </select>   
            </div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.admin-select').change(function() {

    $.getJSON("/users/dropdown/"+$(this).val(), function(data) {

        var location = $('#location');
        location.empty();

        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            location.append("<option value='"+ element.id +"'>" + element.name + "</option>");
        });

   });
});
```

UsersController:

```
public function dropdown()
{
    $input = Input::get('option');
    $company = Company::find($input);
    $locations = $company->locations();
    return Response::make($locations->get(['id','name']));
}
```

I think the issue is I need to set a route to my dropdown function, but I'm not sure what that route should look like.

The dropdown function is being called when I select a company but I'm not getting any data via json.

Comment: You should send a get or post request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is id = $(this).val();

```js
$.getJSON("/users/dropdown/", { id : $(this).val() }, function(data) {});
```

Route:

```
Route::get('users/dropdown/{id}', 'UserController@dropdown')
```

Controller:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     */
     public function dropdown($id)
     {
         $company = Company::find($id); 
         $locations = $company->locations();
         return $locations->get(['id','name']);
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error returning json Object{type="ReflectionException", ...}

Comment: It's something wrong here -      return Response::make($locations->get(['id','name']));

Comment: check in your browser first - localhost/users/dropdown/{id} - id a real value and check what you get.

Comment: in the browser I get ReflctionException (-1) Class UserController does not exist

Comment: I got it. route should be Route::get('users/dropdown/{id}', 'UsersController@dropdown'); I had .... 'UserController@dropdown');

Comment: Actually you van return the raw databas object in your controller metod and laravel Will automatically serialize it Into json.